# What is the runtime complexity of the `BLAKE2` hash function?

Tags: hash, blake2

Assume you want to calculate the `blake2` hash function for an arbitrary input of $n$ bytes. I am wondering about the runtime, in particular:

1. Does the runtime of scale linearly with the input length, i.e., can the runtime of `blake2` be estimated as `O(n)`?
2. Is the landau even something that is sensible here, given how optimized cryptographic operations are on modern day processors (say on an intel-i7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blake2 takes (in either variant) the input, processes it in fixed-size blocks, padding the last block with zeroes to the full block size if required. The processing operation happens in constant time (it takes a constant number of cycles, big-O notation is meaningless since the input size is fixed). The initialization and finalization steps also take constant time. Therefore, the overall operation takes $O(n)$ time.

Answer (score 0):

Blake2 and many other popular hash functions exploit parallelism. So while theoretically the time complexity is $O(n)$ but practically you'd see  something like this for **Blake2b** on 2017 Intel Core i7-8700; 6 x 3200MHz; bitvise, supercop-20190910

| bytes | Cycles/Byes | Total Cycles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 53.8 | 430 |
| 64 | 6.7 | 428 |
| 576 | 3.57 | 2016 |
| 1536 | 3.50 | 5376 |
| 4096 | 3.18 | 13025 |

Source: http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-hash.html

As you can see, for smaller input size, cycles dont scale linearly but for larger sizes it nearly does.

PS: I listed third quartile measurements for cycles/bytes.

Comment: Big O notation is asymptotic, and doesn't count wall time, it counts the number of operations. Parallelizing an algorithm doesn't decrease its big-O complexity. Sometimes the distinction does get made, but typically using an alternate notation.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus Thanks for that. Edited to phrase it better.

Comment: Big-O notation is confusing for many people. It's even worse when cryptographers talk about "constant time" to mean "constant cycle count" and not $O(1)$, since something can be "constant time" by the Big-O meaning but still have varying cycle counts. Or can have constant cycle counts per input byte/block (so cryptographic "constant time" but $O(n)$ complexity (asymptotic linear time). Or worse, since "constant cycle count" really depends on the input *values* and doesn't care about the input length. So you could have a cryptographic constant-time O(2^n) algorithm.